# Block DHCP clients based on strings in hostname

Tags: isc-dhcp

Using `isc-dhcp-server` on Debian Jessie, I'd like to block DHCP requests based on parts of their hostnames - specifically, if the hostname contains the RegEx string somewhere "iPhone|android-". My current solution is to wait until they have a lease, and monitor for those devices, and manually add the MAC address to the Blacklist file.

This black list method is getting quite large (almost 256 entries), and getting harder to maintain.

I understand how to check the *beginning* of the hostname to determine the class, but how do I check from *any* part of the hostname to determine which class to assign it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It sounds like you're after the `dhcp-client-identifier` field, which may or may not be what you call the hostname. According to [`dhcp-eval(5)`](https://linux.die.net/man/5/dhcp-eval), there may be a regex option available. If so,

```
class "iBan" {
    match if option dhcp-client-identifier ~= "iPhone";
}
class "bandroid" {
    match if option dhcp-client-identifier ~= "andriod-";
}
```

And then elsewhere `deny` members of those classes under the appropriate `pool` statement. (Or use a more complicated regex to do it in one class.)

Comment: Just a note, `android` is misspelled

Comment: Testing this out, will report by Monday whether or not it worked (and mark it as such). I also read the documentation you posted, and I am going to try using `~~` instead - case insensitive search.

Comment: Freakin' Awesome! I haven't seen any new mobile devices all week!

Comment: False alarm - had one appear. The hostname is simply `iPhone`. Thoughts?